# Substituting path

Tags: perl, bash, sed

I want to replace path in

```
(setq myFile "/some/path")
```

in a file. I tried to do it with sed:

```
find ./_build/html -type f -name '*.html' | while read myFile; do
    MyFile=`readlink -f "$myFile"`
    sed -i "s/setq myFile [)]*/setq myFile \"$MyFile\"/" sphinx_nowrap.el
    # and then some actions on file
done
```

and with perl:

```
find ./_build/html -type f -name '*.html' | while read myFile; do
    MyFile=`readlink -f "$myFile"`
    perl -ne "s/setq myFile .+/setq myFile \"$MyFile\")/" sphinx_nowrap.el
    # and then some actions on file
done
```

but both give errors.

I've read [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/passing-variable-from-bash-to-perl-in-a-bash-script-524991/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-sed-search-pattern) and also [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/sed-doesnt-accept-$variable-in-bash-script-325935/) -- but can't make it work.

**Edit**:

Here's a perl error:

```
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/setq myFile .+/setq myFile "/home"
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, at end of line
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/setq myFile .+/setq myFile "/home"
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

and here's sed error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unknown option to `s'
```

**Edit 2**:

So the solution is to change the delimeter char. And also sed expression should be changed:

```
sed -i "s!setq myFile .*!setq myFile \"$MyFile\")!" sphinx_nowrap.el
```

Comment: And what might those errors be?

Comment: You might want to add what errors you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like perl (and sed) recognizes the slash in the file path as the regex delimiter. You can use a different delimiter:

```
find ./_build/html -type f -name '*.html' | while read myFile; do
    MyFile=`readlink -f "$myFile"`
    perl -ne "s!setq myFile .+!setq myFile \"$MyFile\")!" sphinx_nowrap.el
    # and then some actions on file
done
```

or for sed:

```
find ./_build/html -type f -name '*.html' | while read myFile; do
    MyFile=`readlink -f "$myFile"`
    sed -i "s!setq myFile [)]*!setq myFile \"$MyFile\"!" sphinx_nowrap.el
    # and then some actions on file
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume your `$MyPath` hold `/foo/bar/baz`. Then the Perl code reads as:

```
perl -ne "s/setq myFile .+/setq myFile \"/foo/bar/baz\")/" sphinx_nowrap.el
```

Your Regex is terminated with the third `/` character. To work around this, we can use another delimiter like `s{}{}`:

```
perl -ine "s{setq myFile .+}{setq myFile \"/foo/bar/baz\")}; print" sphinx_nowrap.el
```

I also added the `-i` Option (inplace editing) and a `print` statement so that something actually gets print out.

But probably it would be more elegant to pass the value aof `$MyPath` as a command line argument:

```
perl -ne 's{setq myFile .+}{setq myFile "$ARGV[0]")}; print' $MyPath <sphinx_nowrap.el >sphinx_nowrap.el
```